# Do not create new nodes, only update existing

Tags: 7, feeds

I have a CSV feed that contains only prices and stock levels. The feed has to update only stock and price of existing products. What is the easiest way to block (just "in case") creating new products for the given feed?

Comment: Did you try setting the node type's default publishing settings to be "unpublished" ? This will probably keep existing nodes (which are published manually by you) published, and new nodes unpusblished, which you can decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to ensure that each created node has a unique id associated with it that Feeds can use to identify it (eg as an existing node that needs updating).

You can set one (or more) of the fields to be unique in the node processor mapping section (admin/structure/feeds//mapping):

[image]

My example takes the generic 'Item GUID', I would suggest that you might instead map **SKU** to **GUID** and then set that to unique (make sure to click both update **and** save).

You then change the node processor settings to Update/Replace:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put empty columns for other fields and fill data for prices and stock levels. E.g:

```
column1,column2,prices,column3,stock levels
---------------------------------------------
       ,       ,231   ,       ,Available 24/7
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure In feeds importer theres setting  option that says update existing node, which will as it sounds will update the product irrespective of other fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue coverage your case
https://www.drupal.org/node/1286298

Issue status still in state "Need works", but patch  https://www.drupal.org/node/1286298#comment-8459327 can help you.